# How does intent parameter insertion work based on entity type?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am playing around with Dialogflow ES and learning by creating a simple chatbot that takes food orders. I am doing the bot in Hungarian (which is not officially supported by Dialogflow, but based on the various tutorials I read so far, it should not be an issue). I have created a custom entity type that contains foods:

[image: Food entity type]

I have picked the Fuzzy matching, because Hungarian is a language that has e.g. accusative case-endings.

- Pizza in Hungarian: pizza (so the same as in English)
- "I want a pizza" in Hungarian: "Szeretnék egy pizzát!" (notice the t letter at the end, which is the accusative case-ending).
- "This is a pizza" in Hungarian: "Ez egy pizza." (notice that there is no t letter here, because it's not an accusative case)

See here for more details: http://www.hungarianreference.com/Nouns/-t-accusative.aspx

I have the following intents:

[image: Intents]

I set the custom entity for each of them.

**And now here comes the strange part** (at least the part that I don't understand): for some reason, in some case, the original form of the paramter is inserted in the response (which is "Tessék! Itt egy $entity-foods" -- "Here you go. Here is a $entity-foods."), and in other cases, the written form (that the chatbot user writes) is inserted. So e.g. even if the end user makes a typo, that wrongly written form is used instead of the original. See the below examples:

1. The "pizza" is mispelled as "piza". It's recognized and the original entity type form (pizza) is included in the response, even though I did not specify the $entity-foods.original in the parameters.

[image: Typo]

2. The accusitive version is used in the utterance ("pizzát"). It's also recognized, but not the entity type version (pizza) is included in the response, but the accusitive form ("pizzát")

[image: Accusative version]

Question: why is this like this? I would have at expected that the response will be consistent, e.g. the same form (either what is written by the user or what the custom entity has).

Answer (score 1):

Both your use cases with your current setup are working as intended according to the documentation with regards to [spell correction](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-fuzzy#spell) in Fuzzy Matching:

> When end-user input could be considered a misspelling of an entity
> synonym, the associated entity may be matched. For example, if you
> define a synonym as "lumber", and the end-user input is "number", the
> associated entity may be matched.

For your 1st use case:

```
Input-> kérek egy piza
Agent response -> Tessék! Itt egy pizza
```

**'piza'** was matched and auto corrected to **'pizza'** which means spell correction worked.

For your 2nd use case:

```
Input -> kérek egy pizzát
Agent response -> Tessék! Itt egy pizzát
```

Fuzzy matching feature spell correction did not work and it returned the original user input (**pizzát**).

Comment: Thanks! I guess it makes sense, at least there's some kind of explaination why it behaves sometimes differently. But I still don't understand why the entity itself can be identified in both cases, yet the spell correction does not kick in in both cases. I would have expected that if it can identify the entity, it will use the auto corrected version...